# How to implement excel BDP() function with Bloomberg API?

Tags: python, excel, api, bloomberg

I'm not familiar with either BDP() or api. I'm just wondering if there is any easy and elegant way to implement this excel function with Bloomberg API? Thanks!  (any language is fine although python is preferred)

Answer (score 2):

What function? BDP is the api they provide to access data.  I think the easiest solution for you to is to msg the helpdesk(hit the help key twice) and ask them for the api documentation.  Its somewhere in bloomberg but I am not at my terminal right now, but the helpdesk not only can give you the documentation they can also show you code samples.  You can also ask to speak to an API specialist, who can help you even more.

Most of the scripts my ex-employers fund were using python, so it def works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will ask them when I have time.

Comment: Or on the terminal: WAPI <go> for documentations and downloads

Answer (score 1):

For python, I have started a project to provide access to the bloomberg desktop api. Check it out and help out if you have some code - https://github.com/bpsmith/pybbg.